# Why tkinter canvas doesn't update when used in a class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am writing a small program, where I want to draw something on canvas. This code works for me;

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from l_systems import Lindenmayer

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Draw Shapes with L-Equations")

    cv = tk.Canvas(width=600, height=600, bg='white')
    cv.pack()

    image1 = Image.new("RGB", (600, 600), (255,255,255))
    koch = Lindenmayer(image1)

    koch.init(
        iterations = 6,
        angle      = 25,
        axiom      = "---X",
        rules      = {"X":"2F-[1[X]+3X]4+F[3+FX]-X", "F":"FF"},
        constants   = "X") # This creates a drawing on PIL image

    # Canvas.create_image expects a PhotoImage
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1) 
    cv.create_image((300,300), image=photo)


    root.mainloop()
```

However, I want to organize my tkinter application as a class, therefore I have tried this code,

```
class main(tk.Frame):

    w = 600
    h = 600

    def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent
        self.cv = tk.Canvas(width=self.w, height=self.h, bg='white')
        self.cv.pack()

        self.render_image()

    def render_image(self):
        image1 = Image.new("RGB", (self.w, self.h), (255,255,255))
        koch = Lindenmayer(image1)

        koch.init(
            iterations = 6,
            angle      = 25,
            axiom      = "---X",
            rules      = {"X":"2F-[1[X]+3X]4+F[3+FX]-X", "F":"FF"},
            constants   = "X"
        )

        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        self.cv.create_image((self.w/2,self.h/2), image=photo)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Draw Shapes with L-Equations")
    app = main(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

In this second case, I don't see any drawing on canvas. It is just a white background. How can I fix this?

Comment: As always add `print` in code and see what's going on with varaibles and which part of code is executed.

Comment: BTW: PhotoImage can have problem in classes and functions. `Garbage collector` can remove it from memory.

Comment: @furas I think you are right, changing `photo` to `self.photo` fixed the problem. Add it as an answer, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you, I add some info about classes in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PhotoImage` can have problem in classes and functions. `Garbage collector` can remove it from memory.

---

**EDIT:**

I could check this (because I have to `Lindenmayer` module) 
but your class could look this:

Almost everything is in class.

Class names should normally use the `CapWords` convention. - see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names). Event SO use that rule to recognize classes in code and use light blue color.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from l_systems import Lindenmayer

class Main(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.w = 600
        self.h = 600

        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.title("Draw Shapes with L-Equations")

        self.cv = tk.Canvas(width=self.w, height=self.h, bg='white')
        self.cv.pack()

        self.render_image()

        self.parent.pack()

    def render_image(self):

        image1 = Image.new("RGB", (self.w, self.h), (255,255,255))
        koch = Lindenmayer(image1)

        koch.init(
            iterations = 6,
            angle      = 25,
            axiom      = "---X",
            rules      = {"X":"2F-[1[X]+3X]4+F[3+FX]-X", "F":"FF"},
            constants   = "X"
        )

        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        self.cv.create_image((self.w/2,self.h/2), image=self.photo)

    def run(self):
        self.parent.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    Main(tk.Tk()).run()
```